# HAProxy path to host/path/

Tags: haproxy

Please bear with me as I am not a coder by nature.

This is what I trying to achieve using HAproxy but after hours of checking, I am unable to make it works somehow.

From

1. domain.com/alpha
2. domain.com/beta

To

1. domain.com/alpha will point to backend1/path/index.cgi
2. domain.com/beta will point to backend2/path/index.cgi

I have tried, multiple ways but come to no avail, I did read about rewrite/redirect but somehow it makes me very confuse. eg "reqrep"

by using the alpha.domain.com points to backend1/path works as expected but I need the path inline because of certificate limitation.

Thank you in advance and if possible explain abit how it works and whats the correct terms (example: rewrite, redirect) so that I can have clue on that and I will advance from there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what I was able to come up with:

```
frontend HTTP
    mode http
    bind *:80

    acl alpha url_beg /alpha
    acl beta url_beg /beta
    use_backend backend_alpha if alpha 
    use_backend backend_beta if beta

backend backend_alpha
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)alpha[/]?(.*)     \1path/index.cgi
    server server_alpha localhost:8080

backend backend_beta
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)beta[/]?(.*)     \1path/index.cgi
    server server_beta localhost:8081
```

Obviously you would then replace `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8081` with the correct locations for your case.

**Explanation**

First, in the frontend named HTTP there are two ACLs (Access Control Lists) which test what is in the beginning of the URL (hence the keyword `url_beg`). The result of these rules are if the url begins with `/alpha` then the variable called `alpha` is set to true and then the same for beta.

Next in the frontend, there are two `use_backend` commands which will direct the request to `backend_alpha` if the variable `alpha` is set to true and the same for `backend_beta` if `beta` is set to true.

As a result the frontend does the work of taking the url and deciding which server to use.

The two backends (`backend_alpha` and `backend_beta`) are almost identical except for the text `alpha` and `beta` and the location of the respective servers. The first command in the backend is the `reqrep` command which you pointed out. What the `reqrep` command does is takes a url, searches for a particular part using Regular Expression and then replaces it with something else. In this case we have this url:

```
http://example.com/alpha
```

In the first part of the [reqrep command](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4-reqrep):

- `^([^\ ]*\ /)` takes `http://example.com/` and stores it in a variable called `\1`
- `alpha` then matches with the `alpha` in the given url
- `[/]?(.*)` takes everything after `alpha` and stores it in a variable called 
  `\2` (in this case `\2` would equal nothing as there is nothing after `alpha` in the url)

Then the second part of the `reqrep` command says take the contents of `\1` (`http://example.com/`) and add `path/index.cgi` to the end and make that the new url to send to the server.

As a result for both alpha and beta urls the resulting url sent to the server is `http://example.com/path/index.cgi`.

Finally the `server` command sends the request of to the appropriate server.

I would like to point out I am not an expert on the complicated Regular Expression  part (I find it a bit confusing as well) but hopefully someone else who knows a bit more can explain it in more detail or correct me if I am wrong.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to find if a user has entered  wwwdomaincom only.  I can't figure out.   checking for `path_beg -i` doesn't work because it appears, even though not shown in the browser address bar, something like this actually comes along wwwdomaincom/HTTP 1.1, hence checking for blank for path_beg doesn't work

Comment: Hi @AllenKing. It's probably best you create our own question rather than asking here. That way other people who may know the answer can help.